# Powers of singular matrices and pairs of identical rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a square real or complex matrix. We’ll call $A$ *special* if among its rows (or among its columns) there are two identical ones, different from the zero vector, *(Added:) and if it has no nilpotent Jordan block.*

Obviously, if $A$ is special, then so are the powers $A^2,A^ 3,\dots$. I am wondering if the converse is true, more precisely:

> **Is there a $k\in\mathbb N$ and a singular matrix $A$ such that $A^k$ is special, but not $A$ itself ?**

Comment: Is there a special motivation for this question? (Not that I don't like it for its own sake :)

Comment: I changed "Zeilen/lines" to "rows", hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Felix: I stumbled about that question when looking at the matrices in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/52370/eigenvalues-of-an-oblique-diagonal-matrix. Sure enough, singular matrices tend to seem much "less interesting" than invertible ones.

Comment: @suvrit: Thank you. Dieser Fehler passiert mir erstaunlich oft. :(

Comment: I'm confused by the added part of the question.  Isn't a matrix without nilpotent Jordan blocks necessarily non-singular?

Comment: Well, I thought of Jordan blocks of size $\ge 2$ of course. Do you think the problem becomes different if in the definition, we just require that $A$ has exactly one zero eigenvalue (= it has rank n-1)?

Comment: Well, with this new condition, the problem is certainly not equivalent to the current statement of the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a non nilpotent example.

Take $A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & -1 \\ 3 & 2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.  Then $A$ is not special, but $A^2 = \begin{pmatrix} 8 & 5 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 8 & 5 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is.  Moreover, $A^{r+2} = 3^r\cdot A^2$ for any $r\geq 1$, so $A$ is not nilpotent.

---

Note that for $2\times 2$ matrices, if a power of a matrix is special, then the matrix itself is.  Indeed, assume that the two rows of $A^k$ are equal and non-zero. Since any special matrix is singular, then there is a scalar $\lambda$ such that the second row of $A$ is $\lambda$ times the first.  This is still true for any power of $A$; thus the second row of $A^k$ is $\lambda$ times the first.  Since they are equal and non-zero, $\lambda = 1$, so $A$ is special.

---

**Added to fit the comments to the question:**

If you assume that only one of the eigenvalues of the $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is $0$, then the answer becomes negative.  Indeed, in that case, $A^r$ has rank $n-1$ for any $r\geq 1$.  Without loss of generality, we can assume that the first $n-1$ rows of $A$, say $R_1, \ldots, R_{n-1}$, are linearly independent.  The last row is then some linear combination $R_n = L(R_1, \ldots, R_{n-1})$ of the others.

But then, if $R_1^{(r)}, \ldots, R_n^{(r)}$ are the rows of $A^r$, we still have that $R_n^{(r)}=L(R_1^{(r)}, \ldots, R_{n-1}^{(r)})$, so the first $n-1$ rows of $A^r$ are still linearly independent (since $A^r$ has rank $n-1$).  If $A^r$ is special, then $R^{(r)}_n$ has to be equal to some $R_i^{(r)}$; this means that the coefficients in $L$ are all zero, except the one in front of $R_i^{(r)}$, which is $1$.  Thus $R_n = R_i$, and $A$ is special.

Comment: Yes, it is not nilpotent and nice. But sure enough, its Jordan decomposition is $M=SJS^{-1}$ where $S=\pmatrix{-2&-5&1\\3&8&0\\1&0&1},J=\pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&3}$. And $J$ contains a nilpotent 2x2 Jordan block...

Comment: I'm still confused by your added condition.  Is it not true that a matrix without nilpotent Jordan blocks is non-singular?  Thus it cannot be special, nor can any of its powers...

Comment: Thank you for the addition. I think you have settled all which can be said about this problem!

Comment: ......very nice!

Answer (score 3):

Take $A= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 & \,\,0 \\ 0 & -1 & -1 \\ 0 & \,\,\,1 & \,\,1 
\end{pmatrix}$.

Then $A$ is not special, however
$A^2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix},$ which is special since it has two identical non-zero columns.

Comment: but this $A$ is nilpotent, and the OP asks for non nilpotent matrices...although by the orig. definition of special, it is indeed valid...so the question needs to be refined a bit.

Comment: Well, he said that *a priori* nilpotent matrices don't yield counterxamples, "as the all-zero vector is not considered".
Maybe I'm misreading the question, but it seems to me that this is a counterexample, since even if $A$ is nilpotent, $A^2$ has two nonzero identical columns, so it is special in the OP's sense.

Comment: anyway, I agree that maybe the question should be a bit refined.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I have refined the question to exclude matrices with nilpotent Jordan blocks. You have indeed provided a counterexample, and this suspected possibility was the very reason I had said "a priori"... This remark is moot now, so I have removed it, too. Obviously I would like to push it a bit further by excluding matrices that feature "too many zeros", so to speak.